# Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, angular8

Angular is new for me. And right now I'm struggeling with my Auth Guard. I get the following exception:  'Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging' and after few seconds my browser hangs. 
The error raises, when I try to log in and route to '/form'.

My app-routing module looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './_helpers/auth.guard';
import { FormComponent } from './components/form/form.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    path: 'form',
    component: FormComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'login',
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and my auth.guard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) {}

    canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      const currentUser = this.authenticationService.getUser;
      if ( currentUser ) {
      return true;
    } else  {
      alert('You are currently not logged in, please provide Login!');
      this.router.navigate( ['/login'] );
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

and in app.module.ts my provider:

```
providers: [AuthGuard, SessionService, ImageService],
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug what does `next` contains in `canActivate` method?

I think that you miss the condition to go to `FormComponent`.

Can you try this config to your router please ?

```
 {   
    path: 'form',
    component: FormComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {authenticated: true}
  }
```